# How to change NumberFormat?

Tags: c#

i have an query. I need to change (`,`) to (`.`) and (`.`) to (`,`) in a number(i.e, `1,234.45` --> `1.234,45`).

I tried `string.Replace()` method. it changes all(.) to (,) or (,) to (.).

Please anyone suggest me how to achieve this.

Comment: Is this a float or a string?

Comment: @ThomasAyoub , i have set datatype as Decimal

Comment: this, to me, looks like an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - could you describe in more detail what you are trying to do?

Comment: Use Double.Parse with en-US culture info, then ToString back using de-DE cultureInfo.

Comment: @Prithiv Numbers don't have a format until you turn them into strings.  You just need to make sure to use the correct culture when you parse a `string` to a `decimal` and when you format a `decimal` to a `string` (that should only be done when displaying the numbers to a user.

Comment: @Thomas , Actually i have an grid control with a decimal column, set the format as "0,000.00". Then it displays as it is. but i need show the number format as "0.000,00" while running application. Is it clear?

Comment: @Prithiv That's the type of information that you should include in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use a temporary character between replacements (e.g.: '_').

```
char tempChar = '_';
string originalStr = "1,234.45";
string finalStr = originalStr.Replace(',', tempChar).Replace('.', ',').Replace(tempChar , '.');
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `ToString` with the [`NumberFormatInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
decimal value = new decimal(1234.45);
Console.Out.WriteLine(value.ToString("N",   new NumberFormatInfo
                                            {
                                                NumberDecimalSeparator = ".",  
                                                NumberGroupSeparator = ","
                                            }));
```

It will output

> 1,234.45